# Back button doesnt work first time after f5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a angular 8 application. And I have a back button. But if you do a ng serve and push on the bakc button it doesnt work. Just if you go back in the browser then the go back button works. also if you do an f5 and you press on the go back button it doens't work. only after it works.

But the funny thing is that if you press the button the first time it steps in the method and also the this.router have been triggered. But nothing happens

searched on the internet. But only found that it works only one time.

So this is the html:

```
<a  (click)="goBack()" class="back">
```

and this is the typescript code:

```
goBack() {    
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.previousRoute);
  }
```

That the go back button works also the first time.

Thank you

```
 previousRoute: string;
```

And this is the ngOnInit():

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.previousRouteService.observePreviousUrl().subscribe(prevRoute => this.previousRoute = prevRoute);
  }
```

and this is the PrviousRouteService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PreviousRouteService {

  private previousUrl: string;
  private currentUrl: string;

  private routeSubject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
  private routeObserver: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.routeObserver = this.routeSubject.asObservable();
    this.routeSubject.next('/dashboard');
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
        this.routeSubject.next(this.previousUrl);
      }
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl(): string {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }

  public observePreviousUrl(): Observable<string> {
    return this.routeObserver;
  }
}
```

If i do this:

```
 public observePreviousUrl(): Observable<string> {
    console.log('previous:' , this.previousUrl);
    console.log('Current',  this.currentUrl);
    return this.routeObserver;
  }
```

I get this:

```
previous: /gezondheid/Measurement/bloeddruk
previous-route.service.ts:35 Current /gezondheid/Measurement/bloeddruk
```

if I do it like this:

```
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

        console.log('previous:' , this.previousUrl);
        console.log('Current:',  this.currentUrl);

        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
        this.routeSubject.next(this.previousUrl);
      }
```

I get an undefined:

```
previous: undefined
previous-route.service.ts:24 Current: /gezondheid/Measurement/bloeddruk
```

Comment: When/how is `previousRoute` being assigned a value? Please add that code to the question as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the post

Comment: @FabianKüng Is it so more clear?

Comment: Much better, yes. What is the output when you console log the `previousUrl` and `currentUrl`? I'm curious what it shows once you refresh (most likely it is both the same and therefore you can't navigate back).

Comment: Yes, they are the same: previous: /gezondheid/Measurement/bloeddruk
previous-route.service.ts:35 Current /gezondheid/Measurement/bloeddruk

Comment: But how to change that?

Comment: What is the output if you log the values directly after `if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {`? There the `previousUrl` should still be the correct one? Otherwise a solution might be to store it in the local storage.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196986/discussion-between-fabian-kung-and-mightycode-newton).

Comment: Localstorage doesn't help.